# Flex 4: Directory Structure

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

I'm trying to build a Flex application and have a question regarding directory structure. In my application you have a main section, which is split into categories and each category is split into sub categories, all accessible through ViewStacks, popups, etc.

For example:

- MyCompany

  - Users

    - Add
    - Edit

When it comes to directory structure, how's best to lay out the folders? Should I do something like this:

- src

  - com

    - myCompany

      - users

        - Add.mxml
        - Edit.mxml

Can anyone give me any tips or advice on whether this is the best approach or if there's another way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about creating an MVC structure, even if you are not using a pure MVC framework.

I would go with
com.myCompany.users.views
here I will add the AddView.mxml, EditView.mxml
com.myCompany.users.helpers
here I will add the UserValidationHelper.as (email validation and stuff like that)

and so on...